# Some settings not changing anything on the frontend

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, porto, settings

I have a newsletter popup that won't stop coming up. I've changed it to disabled, and it doesn't change.

I also can't change the look of my product image gallery. I reached out to the support theme at Porto, and, as usual, they claim that it's not the theme issue.

All of the static content is generating ok, and things seem to be functioning normally, it's just a couple of settings that seem messed up. Any idea why?

I've run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, static-content:deploy, indexer:reindex, cache:clean, cache:flush, and cleared the varnish cache

[image: frontend view]
[image: backend image attachments]
[image: Product image view set]
[image: what the product images should look like]

[image: newsletter settings]
[image: popup still happening]

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can set cookie when popup opens and then check if cookie exsists and restrict popping . post your code, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the popup issue, but it solves the image gallery issue. The global setting doesn't seem to actually do anything, because it's overridden by an attribute called product_page_type.

Setting that made the page behave the way that it's supposed to

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE PATH IN (
                                            'dev/js/merge_files',
                                            'dev/js/minify_files',
                                            'dev/js/enable_js_bundling',
                                            'dev/css/merge_css_files',
                                            'dev/css/minify_files',
                                            'dev/template/minify_html',
                                            'dev/static/sign',
                                            'dev/template/allow_symlink',
                                            'dev/translate_inline/active',
                                            'dev/translate_inline/active_admin',
                                            'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks',
                                            'dev/debug/template_hints_storefront',
                                            'dev/debug/template_hints_admin');

INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope,scope_id,path,value) VALUES
('default',0,'dev/js/merge_files','0'),
('default',0,'dev/js/minify_files','0'),
('default',0,'dev/js/enable_js_bundling','0'),
('default',0,'dev/css/merge_css_files','0'),
('default',0,'dev/css/minify_files','0'),
('default',0,'dev/template/minify_html','0'),
('default',0,'dev/static/sign','0'),
('default',0,'dev/template/allow_symlink','0'),
('default',0,'dev/translate_inline/active','0'),
('default',0,'dev/translate_inline/active_admin','0'),
('default',0,'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks','0'),
('default',0,'dev/debug/template_hints_storefront','0'),
('default',0,'dev/debug/template_hints_admin','0');
```

Try this query and then setup upgrade